# Does aws-cdk support uploading external dependencies for lambda functions?

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to use an external dependency (wink-pos-tagger) in my lambda and be able to deploy it with aws-cdk.  I know there is a manual way of doing it but I would rather it all be in one command with the aws-cdk.  Does aws-cdk support this?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, but [it seems like it's on the CDK's roadmap](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/1435)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lambda Layers - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.LayerVersion.html to build custom packages with external dependencies that can be used in your Lambda functions.

Or you can use webpack and build your functions before cdk deploy.